# Зачем передавать 0 в reduce?

Tags: javascript

Что делает 0 в данной функции?

```js
function sum() {
    return Array.from(arguments).reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b), 0);
}
```

Comment: Почему бы не прочитать [описание](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) reduce?

Comment: @MBo так и не нашел в каком месте это объясняется

Comment: initialValue же

Comment: @MBo спасибо, разобрался

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начальное значение, чтобы не упало на пустом массиве.

А вот `Number(a)` вполне можно заменить на `a`.

Да и вообще, лучше функцию вот так переписать:

```
function sum(...args) {
  return args.reduce((a, b) => +b + a, 0);
}
```

Comment: Получается b преобразуем в число, но если a будет числом в виде строки, то сложит ведь неправильно. К тому же числа на вход подаются необязательно в виде массива. И не совсем понятно зачем "...args" нужно в аргументе функции

Comment: @ИванСорокин, `а` не может быть ничем кроме числа.

Comment: Почему? К примеру передаем sum("2", "5").

Comment: @ИванСорокин, `+"2" + 0`, `+"5" + 2`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.